# Why is my MicroSD card suddenly write protected?

Tags: mount, sd-card, read-only

I have a 16 GB SanDisk MicroSD card that is plugged into my laptop using a MicroSD-to-SD card adapter that is plugged into an SD-to-USB adapter.

It used to work fine, but now I get an error message when I plug the card in saying that one of the partitions can't be mounted:

> Unable to access "userdata" - Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/krisztian/userdata: cannot mount /dev/sdb4 read-only

This is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[  635.485229] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  635.647023] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0723, bcdDevice=94.51
[  635.647032] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[  635.647038] usb 1-1: Product: USB Storage
[  635.647042] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic 
[  635.647046] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000009451
[  635.700240] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  635.700345] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 05e3 pid 0723: 8000
[  635.700392] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  635.700549] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  635.705394] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  636.710912] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9451 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  636.711702] scsi 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  636.958089] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 31116288 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[  636.959123] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[  636.959126] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 80 00
[  636.960057] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  636.960062] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  636.985619]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[  636.989887] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  637.803657] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[  637.841704] EXT4-fs (sdb3): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[  637.867540] EXT4-fs (sdb4): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[  637.867542] EXT4-fs (sdb4): write access unavailable, cannot proceed (try mounting with noload)
[  648.934742] EXT4-fs (sdb4): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[  648.934745] EXT4-fs (sdb4): write access unavailable, cannot proceed (try mounting with noload)
[  655.244375] EXT4-fs (sdb4): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[  655.244379] EXT4-fs (sdb4): write access unavailable, cannot proceed (try mounting with noload)
[  676.986825] EXT4-fs (sdb4): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[  676.986829] EXT4-fs (sdb4): write access unavailable, cannot proceed (try mounting with noload)
```

It says that "Write Protect is on", but I don't know why. I've checked the Lock switch of the adapter. It is definitely in "unlock" position.

And this is the output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/krisztian/boot type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/krisztian/_ type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb3 on /media/krisztian/vendor type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
```

As you can see `/dev/sdb4` doesn't show up and all other partitions are mounted read-only.

On the MicroSD card I have LineageOS flashed onto it. I've tried to flash the image onto the card again, but get this message:

```
krisztian@laptop:~/Downloads$ unzip -p lineage-17.1-20201108-UNOFFICIAL-KonstaKANG-rpi3.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M conv=fsync
[sudo] password for krisztian: 
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
```

Any ideas?

**Update**:

I've tried other SD cards as well and they are all mounted with "Write Protect is on". So I would say that the cards are not the problem. Maybe the USB card reader is broken.

Comment: If you are regularly swapping cards, then there's a good probability that one of the contacts in the reader has gunk on it, preventing a proper read of the card. Outdoor photographers deal with this far too often. See if you can get something into the reader to wipe the contacts. That may be all you need 

Comment: @matigo: Thanks for the suggestion. After cleaning the reader I'm still experiencing the same issue. I think the reader broke down. It's some cheap Chinese piece after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around buying a new card reader and the card works with it. So the problem was simply that the card reader broke.

Comment: In my case, the MicroSD card of my Orange PI (a Raspberry PI clone) got damaged after several failures and freezes while writing on it. It didn't work in write mode even after changing the card reader. At least, it allowed me to mount it in read-only mode to save the data and transfer it to a new MicroSD card.